# How can I get an ordered list to display as a horizontal nav bar in IE8 and below?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, nav

I created a new design with a nav element and a list as the basis of my navigation bar to try to be as semantic as possible. I’ve used CSS to style it so that it's a horizontal list of navigation links. It's encapsulated in a nav element and that is styled to have a black background and be flush with the top of the page and extend the width of the browser window.

I’ve reviewed the site in many browsers and the list is horizontal and displays as expected – even in IE9. However, in IE8 or below it is a vertical list in the top left corner of the page and there is no styling to the nav element at all. I’m using the HTML5 doctype so IE8 should be in standards mode.

Here is the HTML I am trying to style.

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ol>
        <li class="first"><a href="/#menu">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#locations”>Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#about”>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/book.html”>Book Us</a></li>
        <li class="telephone">☎ 555 555 5555</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">
</header>
```

Here is the CSS I’m using.

```
nav {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 6px #6e3000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: black;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#333),to(#111));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#333,#111);
    width: 100%;
    border-color: rgb(216, 35, 42); /* red */
    border-bottom-style: ridge;
    border-bottom-width: medium;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

nav ol {
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ol li {
    color: rgb(251, 243, 161); /* orange */
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

nav ol li.right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

nav ol li a {
    color: rgb(251, 243, 161); /* orange */
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
}

nav ol li a:hover {
    /* background-color: rgb(175,30,30); */
    text-decoration: underline;
}

nav li.telephone {
    color: rgb(251, 243, 161); /* yellow */
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
}
```

And finally, here is the CSS Reset I'm using. It has a HTML5 display-role reset section for older browsers.

```
/* CSS Reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ v2.0 | 20110126 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not styling because previous to version 9 IE didn't support for HTML5 tags such as `nav`, and it doesn't unknown tags.  You can [work around](http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/) it using the [HTML5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).  If you have use for the [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) library, it has the shiv built-into.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I ended up using. Since this is true, do you know what the purpose is of the /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */ block in CSS Reset?

Comment: It is ensuring they all display as `block`.  There are older non-IE browsers that don't explicitly support HTML5 tags but do allow them to be styled.  I'm assuming it is trying to ensure uniform behavior among all browsers; since they aren't defined in the older browsers their behavior may be unpredictable. If you used my answer you might want to mark it as the "accepted" answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

IE 8 doesn't know the `nav` element.

So you need to add it.

Add the following code in the `head` section of your document (before the stylesheet I think):

```
<script>
  document.createElement('nav');
</script>
```

When I have to use HTML5 elements on a page (remember HTML5 still has a loooooooooooooooooong way to go) I always use the following code:

```
<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('footer');
  document.createElement('time');
</script>
```